# как лучше сохранить данные в mysql

Tags: mysql

задача. есть таблица users. в ней поля -

```
 id, date, user_name, ... , country, sity

1, 2/17/2020, василий, ..., россия, воронеж
```

5/15/2020 василий выиграл гринкарту и переехал в сша в майами
как мне правильно добавить эту информацию при условии что предыдущее пмж должно быть сохранено и таких переездов может быть несколько (5-10) и должна быть дата переезда.

пока я вижу что-то типа создания новой таблицы users_meta и в нее сохранять данные по id пользователя, а при необходимости производить селект всех полей соответствующих id. может как то проще можно без доп. таблиц обойтись? типа добавить поле location и в него (например в формате json) записывать эти данные?

Comment: 1) Перевести хотя бы в 1НФ, а лучше в 3НФ. 2) Ничего не удалять и не редактировать - только добавление. И выборка по таймлайну.

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ. из https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0 я понял что мне нужно в эту же таблицу просто дописывать новое поле, но с новыми данными?

Comment: 1, 2/17/2020, василий, ..., россия, воронеж ... ... ... 1, 5/15/2020, василий, ..., США, майами

Comment: нет, нормализация как раз предполагает создание второй таблицы, где будет отдельная запись на каждое местонахождение как минимум с датой приезда (а возможно и выезда)

Comment: если честно вообще уже не понимаю. если не сложно объясните поподробнее

Comment: таблица со структурой id-пользователя, дата заезда, город, страна. Хотя нормализация все еще не полная. По хорошему, города и страны надо выносить так же в отдельные таблицы. Но это зависит от дальнейших действий с этими полями